# Symfony - Twig Entity of type was not found

Tags: symfony

I use Symfony 4.1, and I get a simple error.

I have a relation in my entities (ManyToOne), but I have now in my table an ID with no relation.

In my twig template :

```
{{ agency.brand.id and agency.brand.slogan.id ? agency.brand.slogan.title : '' }}
```

My problem is Slogan for a specific Brand doesn't not exist.

So I get this error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Entity of type 'App\Entity\Slogan' for IDs expId(27) was not
>   found").

I tried everything to test in my Twig if the relation exists, but I get the error everytime.

It's weird because :

```
agency.brand.slogan.id // return 27

agency.brand.slogan.title // generate error
```

I tried to add this in my Brand Entity :

```
public function haveSlogan()
{
    try {
        if($this->getSlogan()) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And to test in my Twig :

```
if agency.brand.haveSlogan
```

But it return true all the time.

How can I catch this error in Twig ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have inconsistent data in your database. The error says the following:

> There is an ID for a slogan in your brand table record (which is 27). However,
>   there is no record in the slogan table with id 27.

Solution: in your brand table change the foreign key to slogan from 27 to NULL. In that case you can check in your template:

```
{% if agency.brand.slogan %}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I've done, the problem is the DB is old and not really logical. Thanks anyway